# How to convert facebook string timestampformate to timestamp ts in java?

Tags: java, facebook, exception, timestamp

I'm trying to convert the facebook string to time stamp formate in java.
When I tried with sample code it works fine.

```
  String text = "2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456";
  Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(text);
  System.out.println("time stamp formate" +ts);
```

But when I put `String text = "2016-02-14T05:22:18+0000";`  (fb Time stamp in String formate) in the same String text it is Giving me EXCEPTION saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:204)
```

Comment: How is that surprising? The error message is clear enough: the format is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using java 8:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
```

Comment: Still better: `Timestamp.valueOf(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(text, Instant::from))` (if you do need an old-fashioned `Timestamp`; still better yet if you can avoid it and rely on the modern classes alone).

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date d = formatter.parse(text);
long time = d.getTime();
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to convert the Facebook Timestamp code that is presented in the JSON data when you download your messages in JSON format, it is a 13 character number like this: 1548410106047.

You must first convert it to a Long datatype, then simply make a Timestamp out of it like this:

```
Long fbt = Long.parseLong(facebookTime);
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(fbt);
```

Once you have it in a timestamp you can do anything with it such as:

```
SimpleDateFormat  sdf      = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY hh:mm a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(ts));
```

The output from above looks like this:
**Friday, January 25, 2019 01:55 AM**

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.